# Flutteronic method of scheduling code to run on the next event loop

Tags: flutter, dart

This is common in other languages.  `setTimeout(fn, 0)` in JavaScript, and `DispatchQueue.main.async() {}` in Swift.

How best to do this in Flutter?

I have used `Future.delayed(Duration.zero).then(fn)`, but I don't like it because like JS's `setTimeout` and unlike swifts `DispatchQueue.main.async() {}` it doesn't really express the intent, only the behaviour. Is there a way of doing this that is the correct way to do this in Flutter.

Comment: What is the purpose of running a delayed function with 0 delay? are you trying to run something in the background? if so, use `async`.

Comment: No, not in the background. The point of running it with delay 0 is that it should get run on the next event loop, but outside of the current context. Specifically, I have a call I want to make in the build function, but it must occur outside of the context of a build function. As I understand `async`, in the context of async/await, it only allows something to be asyncronous, it doesn't force it to be.

Comment: I understand, I've added an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Use `addPostFrameCallback`

```dart
WidgetsBinding.instance
          .addPostFrameCallback((timestamp) {
        print("I'm running after the frame was built");
    });
```

This will cause your callback function to run right after flutter has finished building the current frame.

Note that the callback will only run once, if you want to reschedule it for each build, set the callback at the beginning of the build function.

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    WidgetsBinding.instance
          .addPostFrameCallback((timestamp) {
        print("I'm running after the frame was built");
    });

    return Container();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `Timer` from `flutter`.
Example

```
Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      print('hai');
});
```

`Duration` gives you options with `seconds,milliseconds,days,hours,minutes`.

You can achieve `setInterval` also using `Timer`

```
Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer timer) {
      print('hai');
});
```

But keep in mind that to `cancel` the timer on `dispose`.This would save you from hitting memory

```
Timer timer;
timer = Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      print('hai');
});

void dispose() {
 timer.cancel();
}
```